# What does this "magnitude" mean? and how can I find the source code of this Ccdc algorithm function?

Tags: google-earth-engine

This Ccdc algorithm (first link below) can output several bands (second link below), and the explanation of the "magnitude" is confusing to me. How can I find the source code of this function?
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-temporalsegmentation-ccdc?hl=en

https://gee-ccdc-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lctutorial/change.html#ccdc-api
[image: CCDC function on gee]

[image: the output bands of Ccdc function]

Comment: https://github.com/parevalo/gee-ccdc-tools https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0034425714000248

Comment: thank you for your answer